# NullPointerException trying to use ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I'm trying to use ActionBarDrawerToggle, but i'm getting this error:

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cristianerm.bestflight/com.cristianerm.bestflight.MonitoredDestinationsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

The toolbar was working before i tried to add the Drawer. I found some answers here, but nothing solved my problem. Thank you if someone can help me :)

My code:

MonitoredDestinationsActivity

```
class MonitoredDestinationsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationHost,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitored_destinations)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_monitored_destinations, MonitoredDestinationsFragment())
                .commit()
        }

        val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer_layout,
            app_bar_monitored_destinations,
            R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer
        )

        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun navigateTo(fragment: Fragment, addToBackstack: Boolean) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_monitored_destinations, fragment)

        if (addToBackstack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        }

        transaction.commit()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

MonitoredDestinationsFragment

```
class MonitoredDestinationsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monitored_destinations, container, false)

        // Set up the toolbar.
        /*(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(view.app_bar_monitored_destinations)

        view.app_bar_monitored_destinations.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/

        view.app_bar_monitored_destinations.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_icon_more -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Test item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater)
    }


}
```

fragment_monitored_destinations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MonitoredDestinationsFragment">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MonitoredDestinationsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        >

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_monitored_destinations"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:title="Best Flight"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're using some View Binding thing to automatically assign `drawer_layout` as a variable (instead of doing `findViewById`), but that view and ID is defined in your fragment, not your activity. [The source for ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/058467c/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java) shows it's not actually checking if the `DrawerLayout` you're passing into the constructor is null, so it's just crashing when you try to call that `addDrawerListener` method on it

You probably don't want to mess around with waiting for the fragment to inflate so you can get its view and find `drawer_layout`, so I'll just say the usual recommendation is to put the `DrawerLayout` in your containing activity, with a container to stick the actual content in (like fragments). That way its a consistent piece of UI instead of changing every time you add a fragment, and the `DrawerLayout` will be accessible in the Activity's `onCreate`

There's an example of the way you'd set it up [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)

Comment: Hi, I followed the tutorial, moved the code, made some modifications and it worked. Thank you!